# mysql password works in Terminal, but not in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-snow-leopard

I can log in to mysql through Terminal using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I'm prompted with:

```
Enter password:
```

When I enter the password I get:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor....
```

However, when I try to user the same username/password combination into phpMyAdmin I get the rror:

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

Note: I am using Snow Leopard

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am in Snow Leopard, I had to do the following.

Open Terminal

```
cd /etc/
sudo nano php.ini // or php.ini.default
Password: (enter my password)
```

And replace var/mysql/mysql.sock with the following:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Then in Terminal

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: I moved my MySql to a ramdick (an my socket w/it) and I didn't realize that php would track the socket on it's, but it makes sense! Thanks so much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that either the root is disabled by default on remote host (considering that your mysql server and your http server are on different host), or the remote root password is different from the one on localhost (same reason). 
It would be a way better to create a new admin user rather than using root remotely (the new username is obviously less easy to guess).

Answer (score 0):

It might happen when, there is no **controluser** configured for phpMyAdmin in your database.

By default it is like below from config file.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
```

You can also check existing database users by following query:

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

Wish it will help.